# Pass user context id as header to rest API

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, restangular

I have 2 applications - a laravel rest API and angular front end which are on 2 different domains. It is a multi tenant app where users can belong to one or more organisations and can switch between orgs within the app. I am using session storage so the user can have 2 or more tabs open and be logged into different orgs at the same time. All the data belongs to an org via foreign keys etc. I need to pass the org_id with most requests and am considering doing this via a custom header e.g. X-org-id. This would work nicely with the angular http interceptors and with a laravel middleware class that can automatically scope any data reading to the org id and auto populate org if for any create/update calls.

Is there any issue with using a custom header in this way?

Comment: Awesome. Makes total sense, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user can be logged into several organizations, it would make sense to have the org-id be part of the REST API, i.e. part of the URL.

To elaborate a bit: A custom header can be used for all kinds of purposes, but there are advantages to keeping all the information needed to request a resource in the URL.

That way, URLs can be stored, bookmarked and used without having to rely on the existence of a custom header.

Comment: As a side note, It also helps when you get into stuff like caching. One less header to worry about for stuff like Vary. We've found that having tenant id in the URL is the easiest.